# Drupal vs Wordpress for building website for a product

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I would like to create site for a product,I have built site using HTML,CSS,PHP from scratch,but took me 3 weeks to 4 weeks (3hrs/per day).Now i want to use CMS,so i decided i can use Drupal or wordpress, I don't have very big experience in both.I have used Wordpress for my blog and i don't have experience with drupal.I have followed [node one screen cast](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-drupal-7-with-nodeone-part-1-overview).I feel ok with drupal.But my site will have Home,about the product,Advantages,Contact Us,video, in future Blog,forum.So i am really confused which to use now. . .I have got five days to complete the site and i am not very good in designing or theming.Which  way to go ?Is there any thing other than these,I know python(Django very basic) and rails (Basics)

Comment: Given the skill level you say you have, the time you have, and the amount of work to do … outsource.

Comment: Drupal 2/5,Wordpress 2/5,PHP -3/5,Rails -2.5/5,Django -1.5/5,Designing -1.5/5.Time =>40 hours .

Comment: @And:Sure ,i Will wait .

Comment: Spend 1 hour in internet to compare wordpress & drupal you'll get many answers. But 5 days! It's very less.

Comment: @AgA:ok . . .At the max 1 week i can have. .  .

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress is a CMS. It is more powerful at building "normal site" with a blog or a forum with usual interactions.

Django and RoR are programming frameworks to build web apps with complex user interactions. So forget this.

Drupal sits just in between. It is, however, more of a programming framework than a CMS in my opinion and needs some time before really understanding how it works and how to best use it. Basically, you will have to build your site several times before being satisfied.

Search google and will see lots of comparisons between those four.

Depending on your timeframe, I suggest you use Wordpress and a good coffee machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with WordPress and you plan only static pages with blog in the future then WordPress is the logical choice. I would have recommended WordPress even if you didn't have any previous experience with it. It just fits the type of the site you plan to create.